# Android onscreen keyboard without any other keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

I've looked at several questions and come across several posts, but i'm not able to figure out how to do this.

The following picture shows you the basic layout :
[image]

I've created a [custom numpad](https://github.com/nutrixtech/Android-CustomNumpad) and put it up on the repo.

Currently, when the app opens, the edit text has the focus but and anything i enter with the keyboard will go into the edittext box. This part of the functionality works fine.

**Problem**: When i touch the edittext again, system Input Method with its huge keyboard pops up. How do i completely block it from popping up? Or, can i tell the app to use only my keyboard instead of the system one? (Or is the only way to write a custom ime?)

i cannot use NULL type input at the manifest because doing that makes the caret in the edittext disappear and moreover if there are two edit texts, i wouldnt know which has focus.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things:

1. Programmatically hide it in the whole app:

   ```
   getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
   ```
2. Hide it from the view it would be attached to:

   ```
   InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
   ```
3. Set the input type of the EditText to 0:

   ```
   EditText yourEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextConvertValue);
   yourEditText.setInputType(0);
   ```

Comment: 1 and 2 did not work, it did not stop the keyboard from appearing.
3. It ended up removing the caret, but i do not want that. If that happens the problem is that in a screen with two edit texts, i cannot figure out where the focus is

Comment: The anchor is the EditText that receives input